# Static resources not found in brand new Windows Phone 7 Silverlight app

Tags: windows-phone-7

I've just installed the Beta version of the windows phone developer tools, however now when I create a brand new application using the 'Windows Phone Application" template, I see a number of warnings about static resources not being found
e.g.

> Warning   3   The resource
>   "PhoneFontFamilyNormal" could not be
>   resolved.

Couldn't find anything in the release notes about these being moved, can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: It appears that the Application.Resources section in the generated App.xaml file is completely empty, which doesn't seem to be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct that Application.Resources is empty now. These are now (properly) defined as system resources. E.g. you'll see the Phone brushes in the System Brush Resources in Expression Blend.

Strangely, these don't actually come up as "Warnings" in my environment, but they are pointed out as issues by ReSharper.

You can confidently ignore these warnings and everything should build and run fine. Perhaps you can disable or exclude the particular warnings in your environment?

Comment: Strange, because when I create a new application using the provided templates, these resources are specifically referenced in the TextBoxes that are created - hence the warnings I think.
I did a complete uninstall last night and tried to clear out anything that may have been hanging around from the CTP.
I'll check it out later today.

Comment: Thanks for the info.
In the end the re-install seemed to do the trick, and it is now able to locate the resources and display the fonts correctly.